# how to elimate commas from csv file connection manager while importing

Tags: excel, csv, ssis

Am loading flat file into my table, my flat file columns are comma delimiter. Last column in my flat file connection manager is been appended with commas(,,,,) automatically, i want to remove those commas from my last column.  Attaching the smapshot of my last column.
[image]

Comment: Is this on Windows? Unix? What access do you have to text editors? In vi a simple %s/[,]*$//g command on the original flat file will do the job

Comment: This is not a CSV file. Rather it's a screenshot of Excel rendering a CSV file. Excel is a notoriously bad CSV text editor. I've added a new tag to your question, perhaps someone can help you out with an Excel macro solution.

Comment: what have you tried so far? did you try to edit the connection (data > connections > properties) whether there is an option "fill with character" or something?

Comment: @user1348424: If you want an Excel macro then try recording one to see the code. When the macro starts Simply do a find and replace all on commas in the relevant column.